# Запись в файл при помощи класса BinaryWriter

Tags: c#

Скажите, вот у меня есть есть файл и мне надо записать не всё с начала, а, например, только 3-й объект. Как это сделать, чтобы 1 и 2 не трогать? Я делал так:

```
        bw.Write("");
        bw.Write("");
```

Но тем самым все записи стирались :( Как быть?

bw - это

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Settings.Default.username + ".dat", FileMode.Open);

BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитай метод Seek класса BinaryWriter 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binarywriter.seek.aspx

Comment: Спасибо, сработало.